# AutoFac SingleInstance with streamreader

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, .net-core, autofac

How should i register/configure the container, so that the filereader doesn't have to keep reading the file for every request (which is actually a certificate), the cert doesn't change during runtime

Registration of service into container

```cs
public static void AddMyService(this ContainerBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.Register(context =>
            {
                var configuration = context.Resolve<IConfiguration>();
                var options = configuration.GetOptions<ServiceOptions>(SectionName);

                return options;
            }).SingleInstance();
            builder.RegisterType<MyService>().As<IMyService>()
                .InstancePerDependency();
        }
```

Implementation of service

```cs
public CustomStuff DoCustomStuff(...) 
{
   ...
   using (var fileStream = File.OpenRead(_options.SomePath))
   {
      ...
   }
}
```

Comment: Consider improving the question title to more accurately reflect what you want - a way to read file contents one time and use the result as a dependency. Better question titles will get more eyes on your question and get you better help. It can also help you think of things to search for, similar questions that may have already been asked.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of options here but personally I'd just create a new class to hold the data you're reading, since it makes the registrations a bit clearer. Looks like you don't need to keep the file stream open, you can just read once and forget about it.

```
public class Certificate
{
    public Certificate(string value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }

    public string Value { get; }
}
```

```
private static string ReadFile(ServiceOptions options)
{
    return File.ReadAllText(options.SomePath);
}
```

Then you can just register that as a singleton and inject it into your MyService implementation:

```
builder.Register(context =>
    {
        var options = context.Resolve<ServiceOptions>();
        var data = ReadFile(options);
        return new Certificate(options.SomePath);
    })
    .As<Certificate>()
    .SingleInstance();
```